# Angular CLI - Is there a way to automate HTML5 App Cache Manifest

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli

Is it possible to automate the generation of an manifest.appcache file with angular CLI?

I want to insert the file names of the generated files (e.q main.e94c08b11b957982551b.bundle.js, scripts.4e5f7c7ed99953e49651.bundle.js, ...) to the manifest.appcache automatically.

What is the best way to archive this requirement with angular CLI?

Thanks!

Comment: You're aware that application cache (appcache) has been removed from web standards and is in the process of being dropped? Would you instead be willing to utilize a service worker? @angular/cli has great automated support for service work generation which includes generating a list of hashed resources.

Comment: Thank you very much for the information, I did not realize that.